# How to use configuration file to initialize Amplify auth for cross account deployment of angular project using pipeline

Tags: angular, aws-amplify, aws-codepipeline

I want to deploy my angular project which uses Amplify library for Cognito auth.

The requirement is to deploy the project in multiple aws account like testing, staging, and live. Also, there are separate Cognito pools for each account, so I want to use the configurations file to store Cognito pool details and use them to initialize **Amplify.configure.Auth** object when the app is loading.

I have tried to use **'import from config.json'** but when code is getting build it stores config files data into **main.js** file, So multiple builds are required. I don't want to use multiple build phases in the pipeline as it takes more time and also consumes more resources.

what I want to do is replace the config file using lambda in each account like replace config.json with config-staging.json

Answer (score 0):

I have used a workaround by adding 3 ng builds and replacing config file before each build phase then copied that build files to s3 bucket